# How do I connect to a Websphere Datasource from Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-8

I am using IBM Websphere 8.5.5.8. I have configured a data source `jdbc/Myds`

I wrote a java program locally to have a connection to the server and get records from a table.

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext(); 
ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("jdbc/Myds");
con=ds.getConnection();
```

But this code returns an oracle error `Invalid username / password`

Then I changed code as:

```
    Context initContext = new InitialContext(); 
    ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("jdbc/Myds");
    con=ds.getConnection("usename","password");
```

This connects to the database correctly.
So, it is difficult for me to deploy the application in different servers having different user name and password.

How can I solve this?
Is it a configuration issue in the server or the issue in my coding?.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to configure it on the server. You can use WAS Admin Console to setup your data source with authentication parameters.
In this way you have the user/password configured for each server.
See the [documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tdat_ccrtpds.html?lang=en).

Then, your JAVA code should be:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext(); 
ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("jdbc/Myds");
con=ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: And if the OP wants to change it's application server in the future?

Comment: All application servers allows the user to configure the data source and to setup its authentication parameters. If you change the server, you will have to configure the new data source..

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access it from external application via JNDI name, the recommended way to do it is to define `Component Authentication Alias` in the DataSource configuration. If you will create Web/EJB application located on the server, then you should use resource references and `Container Authentication Alias`. These aliases allows you to separate user specific data that needs to be used to connect to various resources (e.g. Datasource, JMS) from your application.

Such configuration mechanisms exist in various form in all application servers and doesn't require anything specific in the application code.

Answer (score 1):

Answering straightforward to your question, IMHO, it's an architectural decision, therefore not an issue *per se*.

A solution that you could follow would be creating a configuration file, where you would place your `username` and `password`, and that the application would read before establishing the connection to the database.

> *it is difficult for me to deploy the application in different servers having different user name and password*

From the top of my head you could achieve this in two ways:

1. Use a [Java Build Tool](http://technologyconversations.com/2014/06/18/build-tools/) that, using something like a [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), would pack the application with configuration file for a server. The catch is that you'd have to produce a build for each server, if the pair `username/password` are indeed different between servers.
2. Build the application without the configuration file packed and place the latter directly on the server. Using this approach you'd have to guarantee that the configuration file would be accessible in the application's classpath in order to read it.